# Using HttpCookie instead of Session in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I want to use `HttpCookie` instead of `Session` in ASP.NET.

I'm facing problem when I set cookie in login page and redirect it to next page. If I try to access the cookie in the next page it returns null.

**Login Page Code**

```
HttpCookie loginCookie = new HttpCookie("LoginInfo");
loginCookie["EmailID"] = txt_email.Text;
loginCookie.Domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteURL"];
loginCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
loginCookie.Secure = false;
loginCookie.Domain = "/";
Response.Cookies.Add(loginCookie);
Response.Redirect("home.aspx");
```

**Home Page Code**

```
HttpCookie loginCookie = new HttpCookie("LoginInfo");
if (loginCookie["EmailID"] == null)
{
   Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
}
```

Comment: You set the `loginCookie.Domain` twice. Is that right?

Comment: Have you tried to use `Request.Cookies["LoginInfo"]` for reading the cookie?

Comment: Yeah, tried not working

Comment: Take a look at Habib's edited answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to create a new `Cookie` instead retrieve the existing one using `Request.Cookies`

```
HttpCookie loginCookie = Request.Cookies["LoginInfo"];
```

See: [How to: Read a Cookie - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd70eh18.aspx)

The other thing to do is to remove setting `Domain` from your first code, You are setting it twice, Just comment out these two lines.

```
HttpCookie loginCookie = new HttpCookie("LoginInfo");
loginCookie["EmailID"] = txt_email.Text;
//loginCookie.Domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteURL"]; //This one
loginCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
loginCookie.Secure = false;
//loginCookie.Domain = "/";  //and This one
Response.Cookies.Add(loginCookie);
Response.Redirect("home.aspx");
```

Comment: Sorry for confusing, I am setting account id also in login page but not added here.

Comment: Is it because I'm redirecting immediately after adding cookie to response

Comment: Shouldn't it be Request.Cookies?

Comment: @sushmit.patil, there was a mistake in my answer, it should be `Request.Cookies`

Comment: @FabioLuz, thanks, just noticed it and modified the answer.

Comment: Friends, its not working,  
Is it because I'm redirecting immediately after adding cookie to response

Comment: If I set it using `Response.Cookies["EmailID"].Expires = txt_email.Text` , it can be accessed by `Request.Cookies["EmailID"].Value`.

Comment: @sushmit.patil, try commenting out `Domain` setting in your first part of code, it appears you are setting it twice, Just comment out both of those line and try again.

Comment: @Habib, Worked buddy. Post it as answer.